# Target multiple DB vendors in Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Is it possible to target multiple database vendors in a single project with Entity Framework? Like: Sql server and DB2.

Right now, I have created 2 DbConfiguration classes:

Sql server:

```
public class SqlServerEfConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public SqlServerEfConfiguration()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SqlConnectionFactory());
    }
}
```

DB2:

```
public class Db2EfConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public Db2EfConfiguration()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new DB2ConnectionFactory());
        SetProviderServices("IBM.Data.DB2", DB2ProviderServices.Instance);
    }
}
```

---

And also 2 dbcontexts:

Sql server:

```
[DbConfigurationType("TestNewProject.Db.SqlServerEfConfiguration, TestNewProject")]
public class SqlServerDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SqlServerDbContext(string conn) : base(conn)
    {

    }
}
```

DB2:

```
[DbConfigurationType("TestNewProject.Db.Db2EfConfiguration, TestNewProject")]
public class Db2DbContext : DbContext
{
    public Db2DbContext(string conn) : base(conn)
    {

    }

}
```

---

Then I have my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly SqlServerDbContext _sqlServerDbContext;
    private readonly Db2DbContext _db2DbContext;

    public HomeController(Db2DbContext db2DbContext, SqlServerDbContext sqlServerDbContext)
    {
        _sqlServerDbContext = sqlServerDbContext;
        _db2DbContext = db2DbContext;
    }
```

You would expect that the Db2DbContext uses the Db2EfConfiguration, and the SqlServerDbContext uses the SqlServerEfConfiguration. But that's not the case. I am getting an exception when accessing sql server. Accessing DB2 succeeds.

When I remove the Db2DbContext from my constructor, sql server works just fine.

Is there a way to access databases from 2 vendors using Entity Framework 6?

Comment: What's the exception that you're getting (type + message), and can you show the code that results in the thrown exception?  In any event, you're going to want to wall off the two contexts completely (not share the EF objects).  I don't know if this is part of a replication strategy or if the two dbs hold completely different data, but a repository pattern with the use of DTOs is likely to alleviate many headaches now and later.

Comment: I would assume you don't need to do this at all.  In the <connectionStrings> you are pulling from for hte name, provider is there. Make sure they both point to the correct provider.  I don't know that you need a configuration like this.  Then, based on the given conn string, you wouldn't even need 2 db contexts unless they schemas were different.

Comment: I'll try to create a small example application later today (using Sqlite and LocalDb I should be able to create the same issue)

Comment: @DanielLorenz Using the web.config is not an options, the connectionstrings are pulled from an external source. It's two different kinds of data. In one database, the users and user accounts are stored, in the other db you have the application data itself. Using a service layer to seperate things would solve the problem. But I would really want to know if it would be possible to target multiple db's. I'll try to replicate the issue in a small example.

Comment: What DI container are you using? It's sounding more and more like a registration issue (although seeing the exception you are getting would help a lot)

Answer (score 1):

Try concrete instantiation and create two different contexts and connection string to these contexts.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly SqlServerDbContext _sqlServerDbContext = new SqlServerDbContext ();
    private readonly Db2DbContext _db2DbContext = new Db2DbContext();

    public HomeController()
    {
        _sqlServerDbContext...
        _db2DbContext = db2DbContext...
    }
```

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose of DI, but I'll give it a try as well.